# Optimal Table Set Up in Relational Database

Tags: mysql, sql

Not sure if this sort of question is appropriate for stackoverflow (I just made an account), but I'll give it a shot. Redirect me if appropriate. I have tried some searching for this scenario, but I honestly don't know how to describe it other than a long post. I'm not sure if there are some terms that describe what I want. Thanks.

I am using MySQL, but I figure this is a general DB question. I need to create a set of tables that will allow for the following information to be stored, without possibility for conflict, orphans or redundancy. I've replaced my specific example with analogous data that I think will be more universally understood:

Tables (only the important fields are included):

There are workers, each of which has a position attribute, and there are employers

1) Workers

- WorkerID (pk)
- PositionID (fk - Positions)

2) Positions

- PositionID (pk)

3) Employers

- EmployerID (pk)

Those employers may include any number of positions. There is a many-to-many relationship between employers and positions (represented by the linking table "Titles"), but any of those positions may have a different title at different employers. So any combination of Employers and Positions may exist, with a specific title for that combination.

Titles

- PositionID (joint pk; fk - Positions)
- EmployerID (joint pk; fk - Employers)
- TitleName

Also, any Worker can be assigned to any number of Employers. There is a many-to-many relationship between workers and employers (represented by the linking table "Assignments"), but workers can only be assigned to an employer which has a title for their position. So I have built the linking table to link workers to titles.

Assignments

- WorkerID (joint pk; fk - Workers)
- PositionID (joint pk; joint fk - Titles)
- EmployerID (joint pk; joint fk - Titles)

This set up resembles one where you are a contracting agency with a set of workers to contract out, each with different "positions", or qualification levels, let's say. Then you have a set of employers, each of which uses different terminology for those positions. When you assign one of your workers to an employer, their "position" has to match the "position" of that title within that employer. Hope this isn't too confusing.

I have tried different set-ups, but I always end up with something where I can imagine room for conflict (and I would like to avoid redundancy, possibilities for orphaning, application-level validation, or triggers). The above was my best shot to try to create an optimal scenario, but there is a forked route in the table relationships that could result in two different (conflicting) results for a given SELECT query, if the records are not inserted/updated/deleted correctly.

e.g. A record in Assignments may assign a Worker to a Title which does not match his/her position.

Consider the following set of records:

Workers:

- WorkerID: 1, PositionID: 1

Positions :

- PositionID: 1;
- PositionID: 2

Employers:

- EmployerID: 1

Titles:

- PositionID: 1, EmployerID: 1, TitleName: "Junior Programmer";
- PositionID: 2, EmployerID: 1, TitleName: "Senior Programmer"

Assignments:

- WorkerID: 1, PositionID: 2, EmployerID: 1

There are no foreign key violations in this scenario, and I fear this sort of record might get into the DB. In this scenario, a worker (WorkerID: 1, PositionID: 1) is assigned to a title (PositionID: 2, EmployerID: 1) that is for a different position.

I know that there are validation steps I can perform at the application level to ensure no conflicts, but I wonder if there is a way to build the tables and relationships not to allow it in the first place.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a table 'qualifications' to link a worker to titles? Your fk in 'assignments' tied to the qualifications table on that compound key should fail if you try the scenario in question.

I would asked this in a comment but I don't have enough reputation yet so I had to ask as an answer.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you are suggesting. What would the Qualifications table include?

Comment: It would be a cross reference table between the workers table and the titles table so when you add new assignments, the fk to the this table would do the validation you wanted to be automatic. workerid/positionid would be the compound key and any additional columns are optional based on your needs.